# Does FirebaseMessageingService.onMessageReceived need runBlocking when using coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, kotlin-coroutines

I need to sync data when a FCM push message is received. My whole infrastructure used coroutines.
From the looks of it seems that I need a runBlocking, however I'd best like to avoid that, sync my Syncer exposes only regular functions and uses it's own coroutine scope to run suspend functions

```
class SomeSyncer {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope ..
    private val _state = MutableFlow...
    val state: Flow<State> get() = _state

    fun sync() {
        scope.launch {
            _state.value = RUNNING
            doSync()
            _state.value = IDLE
        }
    }
}
```

```
class FcmService : FirebaseMessageingService {
    override onMessageReceived() {
        someSyncer.sync() ?
        or
        runBlocking {
            someSyncer.sync() ..somehow make it wait? maybe the lowercase coroutineScope?
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is runBlocking necessary?
2. Can I still run in my custom scope but have the runBlocking work somehow, without refactoring?
3. What if I just use the 1st variant and sideffect to custom scope, will I break wakelocks? (sync is like 1-2seconds max)
4. Or should I expose a suspend function public api (which I don't really want to, it's never needed unless here)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Firebase APIs, but in `JobService`, the callback has a boolean return value and if you return `true`, Android will let your code run until you call `jobFinished`. You call this at the end of your launched coroutine, and don't have to use `runBlocking`.

Comment: I dug deeper into their source, and yes seem to release wakelocks right away as the callback function returns

Comment: And does the contract for the callback force you to return quickly as well? If that's the case, then there's no way to execute any longer-running code.

Comment: Not really, they say like 10s of work is okay

Comment: Then I think `runBlocking` is the best fit for that API.

Comment: yes but I need to expose a suspend function for that, which I dont have currently, its only used internally as you can see in the sample .. welp..alright, thanks!